# Appended text not displaying

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am using the D3 library and the D3 update pattern in a hierarchical data structure- based on a CSV source file. I am trying to append some text and have it display differently depending on the depth property of the nodes created at each level of the data. these nodes are represented by a circular SVG element and have an associated description property that contains the text.

```
var nodes = chart.selectAll(".node").data(toRender);
var nodesUpdate = nodes.merge(nodesEnter);

//normal nodes
nodesUpdate.select("text")
.attr("x",function(d){return d.x < 180 ===!d.hidden ? 6 :-6; 
 })
.text(function(d) {
if(d.depth>1){
    return d.data.description
}else{
    return;
}})

//special nodes that I want a circular path text for
nodesUpdate.select("text")
.append("path")
.attr("id", function(d){return d.data.id}) //Unique id of 
 the path
.attr("d", function(d) {return getPathData(d)}) //SVG path
.style("fill", "none")
.style("stroke", "#AAAAAA");

 nodesUpdate.select("text")
 .append("textPath") //append a textPath to the text element
.attr("xlink:href", function(d){return d.data.id}) //place 
 the ID of the path here
.style("text-anchor","middle") //place the text halfway on 
 the arc
.attr("startOffset", "50%")
.text(function(d){ if(d.depth<2){
    return(d.data.description);
    }else{
        return;
    }
 })
.style("fill", "none")
.style("stroke", "#BBBBBB");
```

The new text paths are created correctly and are appended in the  DOM when I inspect it. Also I checked that the ID attribute is the same for both the textPath and the path tags, which it is. Am I missing something here as neither the text nor path is displaying ?

Comment: You select the Text and do Not append it. Did you previously append the text?

Comment: yes but this is a second pass add adding text after the first